# iphone sdk problem

Tags: iphone

i compiled my project on iphone sdk 4.2 . But when i installed it in iphone which has iphone sdk 4.0 then its not working. what can be problem and please suggest any solution.

Comment: How exactly it is not working? There's not enough info to help you...

Comment: when i am trying to install .apk file on sdk 4.0 then it demands upgradation.

Comment: apk? are you on the wrong sdk ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double click on your project go to `built` and in `deployment` section see i`OS Deployment Target` change it to iOS 4.0 or below as you wish.
good luck

Comment: did you did for the same profile that you are building against? like for debug or release. please verify that

Comment: so you are building against distribution rite?usually the above solution works, i had that problem before and i fixed in this way